# route cisco sg300 traffic through Watchguard firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco, switch

I need help in determining what I need to research.  I have two cisco SG300 switches (sg300-52 & sg300-28) and a Watchguard firewall (XTM-23).  The internet connection currently passes through our watchguard firewall prior to going into switch A.  Switch B is connected to Switch A via GBIC fiber port.  The internet is currently a cable line so there is no need to pass it through the switch first.

We are in the process of having fiber dropped to the building for internet though.  this presents a problem I am not sure how to resolve and it is what I need assistance with.

I want the internet fiber to go into the second GBIC fiber port of switch A, then immediately route all traffic to the watchguard firewall.  I want all the remaining ports from switch A and B to have all traffic pass through the firewall.  Basically, I want the same configuration I have now without the use of an additional box to convert the fiber to Cat5; I would like to utilize the second GBIC port if possible.

Can someone please help me by telling me what I need to research as I have no idea.  I do networking out of need and I haven't had the need to do anything like this previously.  If someone wants to help me with configuration, that would be great, but I am more interested in learning the process than just editing some configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this can be done with separate VLANs on switch A (basically a separate VLAN for the GBIC fiber port and copper port to connect to the firewall port, call it VLAN 666 if you want).  But honestly, in your environment (in fact in most), the ISP will typically give you an ethernet hand-off at the demarc and not a direct fiber connection.  That would be better overall, no traffic being routed "back" through Switch A and no need to take up a fiber GBIC when it isn't required.

Comment: Thanks.  As I said, they have yet to drop the fiber and it is quite possible that is what they will do.  I do not know for sure if I will be working with internet coming directly into my network as fiber, or if it will remain an ethernet connection.  I was just wanting to be prepared either way so when we get the connection I know what to do with it.

Comment: Before they drop it, simply ask for an ethernet hand off, but every ISP I've worked with has defaulted to it being an ehternet handoff.